# SQLAlchemy 2.0 - Verificar se resultado do select está vazio

Tags: sqlalchemy

Olá,

Tenho o seguinte Model

```
class DBUser(Base):
__tablename__='user'
id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
name = Column(String(100),nullable=False)
```

criei uma rota para retornar o Usuário pelo ID

```
@router_user.get('/user/{id_user}')
def api_read_user_id(id_user: int):
with DBsession() as s:            
    result = s.execute(select(DBUser).where(DBUser.id == id_user))
    if (result.scalar() is None):                
        raise HTTPException(404,detail='Usuario nao encontrado')
                
    return result.scalar()
```

O que ocorre é se o usuário existir, é retornado corretamente, entretanto, a condição result.scalar() is None não retorna None quando não existe resultado nenhum na query. Como poderia estar verificando se a o resultado da Query está vazio?

Ao realizar a conferencia if (result.scalar() is None) é retornado o erro de "This result object is closed."

Obs: Estou utilizando o SQLAlchemy==1.4.41, com o import "from sqlalchemy.future import select".

Obrigado!

Comment: `result.rowcount` te dá a quantidade de linhas presentes no resultado da sua consulta

Comment: Tentei utilizar o rowcount, porém é retornado este erro: 'ChunkedIteratorResult' object has no attribute 'rowcount'

Comment: ja tentou `if not result` ?

Comment: if not result não funciona.